# How to do series in Chart?

Tags: c#, graph, charts

I have a simple series.

```
x = [1,5,2,7,12];
```

how do I make a line graph of this in C#? I tried installing system.windows_forms, but I got the following error, so is there another way to just simply do line charting?

[image]

Comment: This is two separate questions... what were you trying to use winforms for? (which also adds the question of what you are using) and how to plot a chart in c#. The latter is easily googleable

Comment: @Sayse I am trying to use winforms for charting. i am using MS visual studio. I tried googling many options to how to chart in c#, but I keep getting errors when I have to install things. I was wondering if there was a 1 liners type of way.

Comment: [MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1f4afdb6-6da8-4785-937f-aed37d869113/creating-a-simple-line-chart-in-visual-c-2010)

Comment: Address the errors you are getting when installing things rather than looking for a nonexistant easy way. The error you received shows you what you should do - add a reference. Try googling for that as a start - "add reference c#" or "add reference visual studio" will probably give you the answer

Comment: @Sayse thanks. I did that. now, the forms reference is gone from my list, but I still can not use System.windows.Forms

By list, I mean add a reference list

Comment: sorry everyone. I got it. I wasn't using a form project. I was using a exe.